# Rerecording ros bag files leads to different counts on the same topics between recordings

Tags: ros2, rosbag, bagfile, bagfiles, rosbag-record

I recorded a rosbag during testing but realized afterwards that I had published one of the messages on the /data topic wrong. I wanted to fix this data and put it on a new topic but still have the rest of the same test data.

In order to do that, I made a node that subscribes to the msgs on /data, and then edits the incorrect data and republishes the msgs onto /data/fix. I launched this node, then played my bag file, and then recorded a new bag file. When the original bag file was done playing, I waited about twenty seconds before stopping the new recording. I thought that in the new bag file, I would have all of the corrected data on the /data/fix topic.

However, after it was done and I looked at the msg counts on the topics using ros2 bag info , I saw that the count on /data was higher than the count on /data/fix. Additionally, the counts on all of the other topics in the new file were all smaller than those on the original file.

I was wondering why this happened, and if there is a way to make sure no messages are dropped.